# How can I update public knowledge base views for an article?

Tags: knowledge, articles

Our org uses Salesforce Knowledge for publishing technical articles on our  public support site.

However, we opted to use our own independent site built on Site-Core rather than the PKB package distributed by Salesforce. I'm looking for a way to increment the read-only viewCount field on the KnowledgeArticleViewStat object.

I know about UPDATE VIEWSTAT clause for SOQL queries. Unfortunately this only increments the views on the internal app channel.

Anybody have any ideas how to accomplish this via the API?

Comment: Where did you find it updates only for internal users?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I tested this clause in a SOQL query in my org